# Associative memory addressing

Tags: memory-management, cpu-cache

I would like to understand better how associative memory works.In associative memory we have the tag and the actual data being stored.The tag describes where the data came from but what does this mean exactly?

Comment: This is a topic too broad to be answered in one question. I suggest you go through some standard references and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @RinkeshP is it that complicated?Can you provide a useful link or anything??

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking or what kind of answer you are expecting.  I don't know "what does this mean exactly?" means.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking.  It doesn't matter how simple or how complicated it is; we expect you to do your research before asking.  I suggest you do more research, summarize what you've found in the question to make this useful for others, explain what you do understand, and ask a specific question based on that research.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.

Answer (score 1):

Associative memory, also known as content-addressable memory is a memory that you access by supplying the tag rather than an address (using your terminology). For efficiency, the lookup is performed by specialized hardware.

It is useful for instance in paging systems, where you give a virtual page number and the memory manager quickly tells where it resides in RAM.

In software, this compares to a hash-map.

Comment: "the tag describes where the data came from" is not relevant to this discussion.